# Cannot use object of type Event as array

Tags: php

I'm trying to import an event into my Google Calendar account, however my code fails to import due to an error: `Cannot use object of type Event as array` this appears in line 2149 in my script which is located here:

```
$exported_events = array();
foreach($events as $event_id => $event)
{
    $event = new Event();
    $event->setSummary($event->location);
    $event->setLocation($event->location);

    $start = new EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($event['starts']); // Line 2149
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime((object) $event['ends']);
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $attendees = array();
    foreach($event['people'] as $i => $person)
    {
        $attendee = new EventAttendee();
        $attendee->setEmail($person->email);

        $attendees[] = $attendee;

        $event->attendees = $attendees;
    }

    $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

    $calendar_event_id = $createdEvent->getId();

    if(!is_null($calendar_event_id))
    {
        $exported_events[] = $event_id; 
    }
}
```

Now, as my `foreach` loop walks over the `$events` array, it threw an error with `$event['location']` so I changed it to `$event->location`, now it throws an error on line 2149 which is an array item (the array is printed below the page) and if I change it to `$event->starts` it will throw me this error: `Undefined property: Event::$starts` even if I put `(object) $event['starts']` it will still won't work.

How can I pass it to make it work? `var_dump($event['starts'])` returns as a string.

The array of per each `$event`:

```
Array
(
    [location] => Some location in the US
    [starts] => 2012-03-13T10:00:00
    [ends] => 2012-03-13T14:00:00
    [people] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Joan Uton
                    [email] => rnewkj@hotmail.co.uk
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Jack Sparrow
                    [email] => potc@gmail.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Barack Obama
                    [email] => barak@obama.com
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as you are using two types of $event. One as an array and one as an object.

```
foreach($events as $event_id => $event) // $event is array
//...
$event = new Event();                   // array is overwritten by new object
```

Refactor by giving one type a different name.

Comment: `foreach($events as $event_id => $event) {
    $event = new Event();` - that's where you overwrite the array with an object.

Comment: Niko is correct. Using a variable as both an object and an array, in and of itself, will not always lead to errors (ArrayAccess interface). It's the fact that OP is overwriting the variable.

Comment: A common mistake. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your variable. Change the name of one of your `$event` variables:

```
foreach($events as $event_id => $event)
{
    $event = new Event(); // You just overwrote the above variable. Use a different name!
```